# FOLIUM : choropleth map using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, leaflet, folium

I am trying to create a choropleth map using folium, following the example here: https://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/ocefpaf.github.com/python4oceanographers/downloads/notebooks/2015-08-24-choropleth.ipynb.

The goal is to produce a choropleth map with 2 categories of polygon from my "code" column dataframe. Problem is, when I open my map, all polygons are in grey.

This is my code :

```
m = folium.Map(location=[35, 2], tiles='Stamen Toner', zoom_start=13)
m.choropleth(geo_data=mondataframe, columns=['id', 'code'], key_on='feature.id', fill_color='YlGn', fill_opacity=0.7, line_opacity=0.2, highlight=True, legend_name="mondataframe")
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Hi Vincent, what is  `mondataframe`?  A geodataframe?   can you add a sample to your question?